# how get the Geographic location values of Preference panel of IBM Sametime

Tags: java, eclipse

i am using IBM Sametime 8.0.2. in Geographic location link of Preference panel of File menu have some fields like Personal address, City, Postal code etc. Can i get the values of these fields in a Java program or using Sametime SDK (without using any plug-ins).

Answer (score 0):

There's an article how to create location awareness plugin for Sametime
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/location-awareness-plugin/index.html

Since the plugin able to get the location information to display weather information, I think it might be what you're looking for.